# CORS requests with CEFSharp

Tags: cefsharp

I'm utilizing CefSharp.Windows and I'm trying to execute ajax requests via cors with a web api backend. However, I'm not able to hit my web api, and I'm fairly certain I understand why. (file:/// v.s. http).

The problem is I'm unsure how to resolve it. I've looked around and the best answer I could find was suggesting to modify CefSharp.BrowserSettings to allow FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed, and UniversalAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed.

I've tried both and am still unable to successfully execute any of my ajax calls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can we see what code you're using to make the request? The handling configuration might also be relevant.

Comment: Do you mean `CefSharp.WinForms`?

Comment: You can disable security using `WebSecurityDisabled = true` though I don't like recommending that option as it comes with security risks. So only use if you have total control over the pages being loaded.

Comment: You could also try `Cef.AddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry`, may not work with `file:///` though you'd have to test it and see.
Upstream documentation
http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/%28_globals%29.html#CefAddCrossOriginWhitelistEntry%28constCefString&,constCefString&,constCefString&,bool%29